# Connecting a point in space to a curve in xy plane

Tags: calculus, integration, geometry

Suppose that we have a point in space $p(1,2,3)$ and a curve in the $x-y$ plane, and suppose that $k(x,y)$ is a function that describes the unit vector in the direction of the tangent line to the curve $C:(x(t),y(t))$. Let S be the surface obtained by connecting $p$ to the points of $C$. Express the area of S as an integral of the first-type, of some function of x and y, using the function $k(x,y)$.

What I don't get is how can I use the function $k(x,y)$ in order to describe the surface area.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without loss of generality, suppose that we can write the curve as $y=f(x)$. Then $k(x,y)=f'(x)$ is the tangent to the curve. Let's choose a vector with components $\Delta x$ and $\Delta y$ You have $$k(x,y)=\frac{\Delta y}{\Delta x}$$ Since we are talking about a vector in 3D space  we will write this as $$v=(\Delta x, k(x,y)\Delta x,0)$$
You can write the area of the triangle formed by this vector and the vector from $p$ to $(x,y,0)$ as $$\Delta A=\frac 12|v\times(p-(x,y,0))|$$
You can explicitly write out the cross product. Then sum up many of these areas (to get $S$), and put the limit $\Delta x\to 0$, and you will get an integral.

Comment: Thanks a lot! In regard to the first sentence, what if we cannot write the curve as y=f(x)?

Comment: The idea is the same, but you will need to write $\Delta x$ in terms of $\Delta t$, and integrate over that.

Comment: Great! You're really great :)