# Parameterization of a curve

Tags: calculus, analysis, parametrization

A general question: Does every (continuous) curve in space necessary have a parametrization? (even if we cannot find it or express it?)

Comment: How do you define “curve”?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. You can write the coordinates as a function of a distance along the curve from a given point.

Comment: Thank you, sir.
May I ask another question?

Comment: Sure. If it is not related ask it separately

Comment: I've asked a question yesterday and nobody has managed to answer it, I'd be thankful if you can give me a direction to the right way of thinking. Here's the link https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3065245/connecting-a-point-in-space-to-a-curve-in-xy-plane